# Checkbox to be checked flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm a super beginner in programming and flutter. In my application I need my checkbox to be checked. Any ideas? :)

```
// Check Todo
  Widget _todoTask(context, task) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: Checkbox(
        value: task.status,
        onChanged: null,
      ),

      //Delete TodDO
      title: Text(task.message),
      trailing: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.close),
        onPressed: () {
          var state = Provider.of<MyState>(context, listen: false);
          state.removeTask(task);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the way how checkbox works..

```
bool checkedValue = false;
Checkbox(
                              tristate: false,
                              checkColor: Colors.red,
                              activeColor: Colors.white,
                              value: checkedValue,
                              onChanged: (newValue) {
                                setState(() {
                                  checkedValue = newValue;
                                });
                              },
                            ),
```